# how to pass parametr to form urlAction?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I got HttpPost for removing property:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public void RemoveProperty(int id)
    {
        propertyManager.Delete(id);
        Response.Redirect("EditProperties");
    }
```

and in my cshtml file i got combobox and i need to get selected option and pass it as id for removeproperty,my cshtml part:

```
        <form action="@Url.Action("RemoveProperty", "Admin")" method="post" id="remove_property">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Remove Property</h3>
                @*<input name="id" value="" id="removedid" />*@
                <select class="form-control" id="prop_id" name="id">

                    @foreach (var prop in Model)
                    {
                        <option value="Characteristic_Id">@prop.Id</option>

                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <button onclick="" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </form>
```

I know how to get text from selected combobox with jquery:

$("#prop_id option:selected").text();
But quetion is how to pass this param to form ??

Comment: The same way, using the form and its attribute: `$( "form" ).attr( "action", "new.url" );`

Answer (score 1):

You may use a hidden input field .
also use javascript change function on select box
when change select-box you can put selected text into hidden field.

Comment: What am i doing wrong?    ` $("#prop_id")
        .change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $("#prop_id option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
            });
            $("#removeid").text(str);
        }).change();`

Comment: Ok i just forgot that for input i need to set val not text

Comment: replace this
$("#removeid").text(str);

Comment: with 
$("#removeid").val(str);

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#prop_id")
    .change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("#prop_id option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        $("#removeid").val(str);
    }).change();
```

Solution!